# Manage SSL Certificates for multi-tenant app

Tags: apache, ssl, saas

I have developed a multi tenant app, using PHP and Apache. By default each client has a free subdomain like customer.app.com. But they can point their custom domain to the application, For this they needs to change the A record of their domain to point to the IP of the app.
One of our users, wants to use his custom ssl certificate, to run the app via https in his custom domain.
My question, is how i can make to allow all customers, can use their custom ssl certificate in their domains.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make this work is to make an entry into Apache for each subdomain, so it knows what certificate to load. You could make one giant `.conf`, or you could make one `.conf` per subdomain. Make sure you're using a version of Apache that supports [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) (Apache 2.2.12 or later), or you'll have to have an IP per certificate.